# Azure Search for Blob Storage is not working.

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

Step 1: I have created a General Purpose Blob Storage (block blob) and a container (access policy set to "container") in it. Also added 19 documents (pdf, xlsx, docx, ppt, png, jpg, txt) and all documents are displayed in azure portal --> Blob Storage Container.

Step 2: Created Azure search (basic tier) and followed this article and performed the following.

Step 3: Created a datasource

```
POST https://anysearch.search.windows.net/datasources?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview
Content-Type: application/json
api-key: adminkey

{
    "name" : "blob-datasource",
    "type" : "azureblob",
    "credentials" : { "connectionString" : "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorage;AccountKey=givenkey==" },
    "container" : { "name" : "containername"}
}
```

Step 4: Created an index

```
POST https://anysearch.search.windows.net/indexes?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview
Content-Type: application/json
api-key: adminkey

{
    "name" : "my-target-index",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false },
        { "name": "content", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false }
    ]
}
```

Step 5: Created an indexer.

```
POST https://anyearch.search.windows.net/indexers?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview
Content-Type: application/json
api-key: adminkey

{
  "name" : "blob-indexer",
  "dataSourceName" : "blob-datasource",
  "targetIndexName" : "my-target-index",
  "schedule" : { "interval" : "PT5M" }
}
```

Step 6: Run index stats and got the below result - DOCUMENTCOUNT = 0

```
GET https://anysearch.search.windows.net/indexes/my-target-index/stats?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview
api-key: [admin key]

{
  "@odata.context": "https://mydocsearch.search.windows.net/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2015_02_28_Preview.IndexStatistics",
  "documentCount": 0,
  "storageSize": 1728
}
```

Step 7: Searched for the word "process" and got the below result

```
GET https://anysearch.search.windows.net/indexes/my-target-index/docs?api-version=2015-02-28&search=process

{
    "@odata.context": "https://mydocsearch.search.windows.net/indexes('my-target-index')/$metadata#docs(id,content)",
    "value": []
}
```

What went wrong here ? Why the document count is 0 ? Why the word "process" or any other search word is not returning any results ?

Please help.

Thanks

Bhanu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure indexer runs successfully before you can search for the documents. You can monitor indexer status in the portal or programmatically, and this will usually tell you why documents are not being indexed. In your case, the container has jpeg and png files, which are not supported (by default, this situation stops indexer execution). Please review the list of supported formats [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage/#supported-document-formats).

Comment: That worked like a charm!! Thanks so much. I thought non-supported files will be ignored by the indexer. Thanks for pointing it out. I deleted the jpeg and png files from the blob and ran the indexer again. It worked.

Comment: Great to hear that. If you'd like indexer to automatically skip text extraction for unsupported formats (but still extract some storage metadata), please vote for this [UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/15094944-blob-indexer-should-continue-indexing-documents-af)